# Is it possible to extract data from a Google Map that is embedded within an Android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, web-scraping

I've seen a lot of posts about being able to scrape data from a Google Map embedded in a website, however I haven't been able to find any information about scraping from a Google Map embedded within an Android app, and was wondering if this is possible.

I thought perhaps it may be possible using an emulator on a PC, but not sure. Keen for anyone's input.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Please take note that scraping data from Google Maps is against the Terms of Service as per [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services.)

Comment: Should have clarified, it's the app developer's data I want to scrape from the map, their waypoints, not the Google Map data itself. The map is only in their app and not available on a website.

Comment: Then you should ask the developer of that app if it is okay for them to provide you that data. You won't need to scrape their data if they would provite it themselves.